# SharePoint list update item takes more than 5 seconds

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

We have the Sharepoint 2016 hosted on prem with a minimum set of services running on the server. The resource utilization is very low and the user base is around 100. There are no workflows or any other resource consuming service running.

We use list to store and update information for certain users with the help of a form for the end user. Of recent, the time consumed for the update has increased to over 6 seconds for a list data update.

Example:
https://sitename_url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('WFListInfo')/items(15207)

This list has about 15 items, mostly numbers and single line text or number or DateTime. 
The indexing is set to automatic.

As part of the review, we conducted a few checks and DB indexing on our cluster, however there is no improvement.

Looking forward to any help / suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: is it OOTB? Please check CPU and  Node runner  may be search using  your Resources. do check SharePoint Log  as well to get proper issue

Comment: `This list has about 15 items` Do you mean fifteen columns/fields? Your example retrieves an item with an ID of 15207, which causes me to suspect the list has a lot of items in it.